# Convert 2 array to 1 Object Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 array:

```
Array1 = ["a", "b"];
Array2 = ["banana", "food"];
```

I hope result:

```
Array = [{name : "a", value: "banana"}, {name : "b", value: "food"}];
```

Comment: Better not to shadow the global `Array` object...

Comment: Post some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to stack over flow. Stack over flow is not a code feeding website please show us what you have tried so far. are you expecting a json output?

Answer (score 2):

You can use map to merge these together.

Here is a code pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGWgoe?editors=0011

```
let nameArray = ["a", "b"]
let valueArray = ["banana", "food"]

let merged = nameArray.map((item, idx) => {
  return { "name": item, "value": valueArray[idx] }
})

console.log(merged)
```

Please note though that if your names and values are not in order and you need to specifically match them up it may not be the best solution

Answer (score 1):

```js
 let Array1 = ["a", "b"]; 
 let Array2 = ["banana", "food"];

//Array = [{name : "a", value: "banana"}, {name : "b", value: "food"}];

let finalArray = [];

Array1.forEach((value,index) => {
  let obj = {};
  obj.name = value;
  obj.value = Array2[index];
  finalArray.push(obj);
})

console.log(finalArray)
```

Assumption size of both array are exactly the same.

Using `forEach` to loop thru first array, taking the value and index, and using the index to retrieve value from second array

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```js
let Array1 = ["a", "b"]; 
let Array2 = ["banana", "food"];

let Array3 = Array1.reduce((a,v,i) => {
    return a.concat([{"name":v,"value":Array2[i]}]);
},[]);
console.log(Array3);
```